# Can Typescript or TSlint warn for implicit typecasts

Tags: typescript, tslint

When objects in typescript have the have the same fields, or All fields of class `B` are also in class `A`, then class `B` is also an instance of class `A` according to the typescript type checker. See the following example:

```
class A {
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
}

class B {
    foo: string;
}

function convertAtoB(input: A): B {
    return input;
}
```

In this example, `convertAtoB()` is supposed to convert the input of type A to an instance of type B. However, the current implementation does not yield any errors or warnings, because class `A` has the same property `foo` as `B`. The returned value now contains both fields `foo` and `bar`, which is undesirable.

Are there any compiler flags, TSlint addons or other tricks that could warn about this scenario or throw a (compile time) error.

Comment: Structural typing sometimes produces weird results such as this. TS will not warn about this, not sure about TSLint. While not a general solution, adding a private field to B will ensure that such aliasing is not possible

Comment: Yes, that would work. However, in my case `A` is the database entity object, and `B` the corresponding dto object, so adding (private) fields to `B` would change the API output, which is not desirable.

Comment: Not necessarily. If the private is unused it will only exist for compilation, it would not have any runtime impact. Somethin like `class B { private __typeNonAliasingGuard: undefined }`